# Simplest way to draw many thousands of lines with transparency

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I'm looking for the simplest way to draw many lines (~20000) reasonably fast with either transparency support or sub pixel width or both, so that they don't just create a totally black image when layered over each other.

I tried matplotlib, but since every single line is it's own axis, it's very slow, though it looks the best so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# test data in format my real data will use

test_data_as_lines = [((random()*2000, random()*2000),
                        (random()*2000, random()*2000))
                        for x in range(0,20000)]

#format for matplotlib and plot

fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axes= fig.add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.9,0.9])

for i in test_data_as_lines:

    x = (i[0][0],i[1][0])
    y = (i[0][1],i[1][1])

    axes.plot(x,y, 'black', linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Is there a faster way to do that?

I also tried drawing with PIL, but it doesn't support sub pixel line widths and the alpha transparency can only be applied to the whole image, not individual elements:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

test_data_as_lines = [((random()*1000, random()*1000),
                        (random()*1000, random()*1000))
                        for x in range(0,20000)]

im = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

for i in test_data_as_lines:

    draw.line((i[0][0],i[0][1], i[1][0], i[1][1]), fill=(0, 0, 0), width=1)

im.show()
```

This just draws a black square.

Finally I tried the simple graphics.py example library by John Zelle, but this also doesn't support transparency or sub pixel widths and is even slower. It's based on tkinter which I believe has the same limitations so I didn't bother with that.

I was trying to avoid pygame. Is that my best option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of the for loop will make your code simpler and faster. Since the method `plot` can cope with several lines at once, you can use

```
axes.plot(*test_data_as_lines, alpha=0.5, color="black", linewidth=0.1)
```

On my laptop and with 5000 lines, it takes about 93 seconds to execute the code using the for loop while the above command takes about 10 seconds

Comment: This is the perfect solution; definitely the correct way to approach it